# Can I call PyString_InternFromString("pvp_level") in gdb?

Tags: python, gdb

Next is output of my test:

```
(gdb) p PyString_InternFromString("pvp_level")
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
PyObject_Malloc (nbytes=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/obmalloc.c:899
899     ../Objects/obmalloc.c: No such file or directory.
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(PyString_InternFromString) will be abandoned.
```

When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.

Comment: Are you debugging python2 interpreter ?

Comment: Yes, my python version is 2.7.9.